# Spring Cloud Config client unable to /refresh in Grails 3 app

Tags: grails, spring-cloud-config

I've successfully stood up a Config Server (git repo backed) to serve up dynamic config properties to my config client REST service in `grails 3.3.0` and `groovy`.

The client loads its config on startup perfect.  When changes are made via git repo, the config server see's them.

When I hit `/refresh` on the client, it sees the changes as well when I hit the actuator endpoint `/env`. There's the updated property. No errors and works perfectly.

Problem:

`/refresh` doesn't change the simple property (`ad.username`) in the running app. It continues to use the old one.
Here's what is in my `Grails service` class:

```
@RefreshScope
@Transactional
public class MyService {

    @Value('${ad.username:defaultLdapUsername}')
    String username

    @Value('${ad.password:defaultLdapPassword}')
    String password

    @Value('${ad.hostname:defaultLdapHostname}')
    String hostname

...
}
```

`@RefreshScope` doesn't work.  I tried a separate `MyConfig.groovy` with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ad")` but no luck.

Do I `@Autowired` a bean in the `Grails` service class?

I'm not sure where the problem is and could use a bit of help or sample project/code.

Grails 3 *is* Spring Boot, but I'm wondering if there is some difference here.

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely need the @RefreshScope annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't think that's true.  Other than `@RefreshScope` annotation not working on my Grails service class, a separate class with `@ConfigurationProperties` seems to be an alternative approach.  Something is not listening for a `EnvironmentChangeEvent` but i'm not sure what.  Is there something special about my service class?  Not sure.

Comment: If you want to make a public git repo or something I would be happy to help work through this

Answer (score 0):

I would add one of these for my next step in debugging:

```
@EventListener
public void refresh (RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent e ) {
logger.info(“refreshed”); 
}
```

Comment: Good idea.  Included code and logs show: `refresh... e: org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent[source=__refreshAll__]`, /env endpoint shows the change, but the properties still use the old value.

Comment: Are they using the old value from the configs, or the default value?

Comment: The old value from the configs that were (successfully) pulled from the config server on startup.  I have defaults set in the `@Value` and those are never used.  If i /restart or /shutdown the app it (of course) pulls the latest value from git repo via the config server, but I want to refresh the value(s) at runtime.  Since I see the changed value in /env after a /refresh, i'm thinking there must be some cache used for the all the properties that is not being invalidated.  I wish there was some error, but everything works except the properties don't change after /refresh.

Comment: And you have @RefreshScope around your properties?

Comment: Well, if my service class is correct: `@RefreshScope
@Transactional
public class MyService {


   @Value('${ad.username:defaultLdapUsername}')
   String username

   @Value('${ad.password:defaultLdapPassword}')
   String password

   @Value('${ad.hostname:defaultLdapHostname}')
   String hostname

}`